# Ubuntu Not Booting/Freeze at Startup

Tags: startup, freeze, automount, mountpoint

Ubuntu 11.04 is not booting up with the following error message at startup

/device/sda2 is not ready or not present...
/device/sdc2 is not ready or not present...

Then the screen just hangs.

/device/sda2 is a partition that doesnt even exist in my system as far as I know.

/sdc2 is a NTFS partition.

TIA!

//edit

So apparently, I am having problems with the mounting table, but I can't access it cause Ubuntu is down. I've tried editing 'fstab' using a LiveCD, but it's not showing the proper mounting table. If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like your grub is improperly configured.  You may need to edit it to point towards the correct partition.  I would just recommend downloading a grub rescue disk or try the directions from this site:

http://microdotsagamedev.wordpress.com/2007/06/08/repair-your-grub-loader/

Comment: The link you provided is a bit outdated, the instructions don't work with GRUB 2. Where can I find a GRUB rescue disk?

Comment: ahhh my apologies, I haven't moved to GRUB 2 and I forget about it alot.  I'll go look and see if i can't find the link i used for my rescue grub.  give me some time though, as i have way too many FF bookmarks ><

Comment: mmm i may have gotten ahead of myself.  I think I got confused and am confusing "grub-mkrescue --output=rescue.iso /boot/grub" with an actual downloadable iso for grub rescue.  When you correct your grub though that will be a valuable command to have so you won't be stuck again =P.  let me dig some more though I'm sure i've got a grub 2 link somewhere in here.

Comment: ok this is the best i can find:   [link]http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20Bash%20Commands.html#Re-install_GRUB_from_Live_CD    That's got a full page worth of information on grub2.  I would look specifically on how to reinstall grub from a live cd.  there are directions on the page, hope it helps =/

Comment: That didn't work! followed the instruction from that link and it wiped out my Windows MBR, just finished restoring it. :(

Comment: Setting up Grub shouldn't of touched your windows install.  Sorry if it gave you issue.  I'm not sure where else to point you, but I do wish you luck and hopefully someone with a higher technical knowledge can answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

So I realize what the real cause of the issue is, it's not a GRUB error, rather a auto-mounting issue. I am trying to edit 'fstab', but I can't do it cause my Ubuntu is down, and I've tried running it with Live CD as well, but that didn't work. Hope someone can point me in the right directing so I can fix my mounting table.

Comment: what happened when you tried to edit fstab with the live cd? what specifically didn't work?